# Append date to SFTP using mput for multiple files in shell

Tags: shell, jenkins, ssh, sftp

I'm doing a local to remote server automated file transfer upon building the job in Jenkins
Using the execute shell in the build section, I have this code

```
ssh root@10.x.x.53 '
sftp -v -o IdentityFile=/root/.ssh/userkey userkey@10.x.x.11 <<EOF
lcd "/NAS/Migration/Automation"
mput *.*
ls
bye
EOF
'
```

Upon using different stuffs like the `date(date +%D%H%M%s)` and `mput *.* *.*.%TIMESTAMP#yyyyddmmhhnnss%` (which is I believe used in batch, but ain't working here), I cannot append a date to the end of all files copied to the remote server.

I want the all the files that is being uploaded renamed with a timestamp

```
file1.tar --> file1_010822235959.tar
file2.tar --> file2_010922000059.tar
randomzipfile.zip --> randomzipfile_010922030659.zip
filetype.gzip --> filetype_010922153041.gzip
```

Is this possible in the execute shell in Jenkins?

Comment: `\`date +%D%H%M%s\`` ?

Comment: Here you are using the `mput` command that `sftp` supports.  And it does not add timestamps automatically.  Two ways around it: **1** copy your files to a temp directory, and give the files the names you want (with date).  then mput these.  **2** `put` allows you to specify the destination filename.  But you have to write in some loop to put each file one by one.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Tried that as a variable, it's not working, or maybe I used it in the wrong way.

Comment: @Nic3500 I'm going to consider those. I think the first option is the easier route here. SFTP commands are too limited so maybe it is the right way if there's nothing else to make a workaround with this problem. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I didn't read our question carefully. No matter the syntax for injecting the timestamp, it of course cannot work together with uploading multiple files. – Btw, note that in `sftp`, there's no `mput` (it "works" only because `sftp` treats `mput` as an undocumented alias to `put`, which works as `ftp` `mput`). – You will have to follow the advice by @Nic3500.